# Why doesn't LWJGL recognize my GLFW version?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I have written a simple program with LWJGL. The problem is that every time I try to run the app, I encounter this error:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: Thread[main,5,main]: No context is current or a function that is not available in the current context was called. The JVM will abort execution.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin(Native Method)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

The error is misleading, as I did actually call `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)` and `GL.createCapabilities()`.

I tracked the error to the `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)`. It seems that when I remove this and the `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)` line, the app will run.

What I do not understand is why does it happen, as I do actually have a GLFW 3.3 dependency in `pom.xml`.

Here is my code:

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <classifier>natives-windows</classifier>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <classifier>natives-windows</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        glfwInit(); // Initialize GLFW

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // GLFW version 3
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); // GLFW version 3.3
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); // GLFW uses CORE profile

        long window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello Triangle", 0, 0);

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();

        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
            glClearColor(0.05f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 1.0f); // Wipe drawing from previous frame with a black color
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear color buffer and depth buffer

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
            glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
            glVertex2f(0f, 0.5f);
            glEnd();

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // Swap front and back buffer
            glFlush(); // Empties buffers - improves performance
        }

        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?  If it's MacOS you might want to try setting the [`GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT_hint) window hint to `GL_TRUE`.

Comment: @G.M. windows 10 build 19044.1466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting OpenGL 3.3 core (the "3.3" is *not* the LWJGL or GLFW version 3.3 - it is the *OpenGL context* version you are requesting), which does not have the deprecated OpenGL functions available, that you are trying to use - `glBegin` and `glVertex2f`.

The error message hints at that:

> No context is current or **a function that is not available in the current context** was called.

There is also a misunderstanding. To clarify, the following comments in your code are misleading/wrong:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // GLFW version 3
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); // GLFW version 3.3
```

The window hints `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` and `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` do not specify which version of the *GLFW* native library to use, but which *OpenGL* context version GLFW will request from the OS/driver for the OpenGL context created by the next call to `glfwCreateWindow()`.

Either use modern OpenGL or request a lower OpenGL version, e.g. 2.1, by omitting the `glfwWindowHint()` calls. In that case, it is up to the driver which OpenGL context version it is giving you. On Windows (with NVidia) it will be the highest available OpenGL compatibility version (such as 4.6) supported. On macOS it will be 2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "supported"? Is it related to the hardware, newer GPUs supporting a later OpenGL context version?
Also, beside drawing with these deprecated functions and drawing with buffers, is there any other way to draw in OpenGL?